# How to get a character which is between other two characters

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a variable, which has the directories of my PC. I want to count and get the partitions I will write inside the variable.

```
$test = "D:\hey,D:\bye,C:\AnotherDirectory"
```

I want to get an output like this:

```
D=2
C=1
```

If possible I would like to put them in a variable.
I looked a bit in regex, and found that with this code `[A-Z]:` it matches the `D:`, `D:`, and `C:` in https://regexr.com/, but I have no idea how to implement it or how to get the value it gets after.

Comment: Reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions) usually helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a list of the frequency of each drive letter like this:

```
$test = "D:\hey,D:\bye,C:\AnotherDirectory"

[Regex]::matches($test.Split(','), "[a-zA-Z](?=:)") | 
    Group-Object Value -NoElement
```

Which gives output like this:

```
Count Name                     
----- ----                     
    2 D                        
    1 C
```

If you want them in the format `C=1`, then only a small change is required:

```
[Regex]::matches($test.Split(','), "[a-zA-Z](?=:)") | 
    Group-Object Value -NoElement |
        ForEach-Object {
            "$($_.Name)=$($_.Count)"
        }
```

Which produces:

```
D=2
C=1
```